# Cordova push-Ionic: How to handle event notifications clicked when application off

Tags: android, push-notification, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm doing an application which receive notification from GCM and APN. I used "$cordovaPush:notificationReceived" event to detect if got new notification. When the application on, this event can detect. But when I turn off the app and get notification, then I click to the notification, the app opend and nothing happen. I try to google also but I'm not sure other pp have same problem. Can you show me what is the best solution? 
Thanks!